# OAuth 2.0 server- and client-side misunderstanding

Tags: oauth

I'm following the description about [server and client side OAuth 2.0](https://yeti.co/blog/client-vs-server-oauth-flows-with-rest-apis/).
I've got some questions:

1. Why in server side there is need to "trade the authorization code for an access token" (point 7 from link above)? Why in point 6. the OAuth server (Facebook) cannot send the token instead of the authorization code?
2. Based on this description, the client-side looks much more simpler.
   Why in this way we do not need to "trade the authorization code for an access token" and get the token immediately?
3. When would you choose client- and when server-side?

Answer (score 0):

a. because the backchannel allows for the server to authenticate
    itself on it when exchanging the code, that allows for a more
    secure/trusted/locked-down setup

b. because it is better not to expose tokens client-side if
    they're only going to be used server-side; the `code` is very short-lived
    and one-time usage only, as opposed to the `access_token`

c. as said server-side is more secure since it allows the server to authenticate 
    but if you only have a client (Single Page Application) your only option is to
    deliver the token directly client-side; also, if no authentication is possible 
    on the backchannel, both options are the equal from a security perspective;
    the only advantage of a client-side flow in that case is that it is more direct

Comment: Could you be more precise? a) why it is more secure? what are the security flows? b) I  don't know on which question it is answer?, c) So what if I need SPA in Angular? Then I have to put secret code in js and everyone can see it?